# RuntimeException - bad second byte at 19

Tags: codenameone

Following is the error log from App in the production. what is the easy way to understand the bad second byte issue here. Provide me any guidance here.
This error getting thrown on different bytes..sometimes at 2 and sometimes at 19 etc. I'm not able to reproduce this issue on simulator. This happens rare but I'm not sure  what is causing this issue.

```
[EDT] 0:23:57,929 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - bad second byte at 19
   java.lang.RuntimeException
    at java_io_DataInputStream.decode:207
    at java_io_DataInputStream.decodeUTF:187
    at java_io_DataInputStream.decodeUTF:181
    at java_io_DataInputStream.readUTF:177
    at com_codename1_io_Util.readUTF:1081
    at com__server_Activity.internalize:571
    at com_codename1_io_Util.readObject:714
    at com_codename1_io_Util.readObject:689
    at com_codename1_io_Storage.readObject:264
    at com_server_ServerImpl.getActivitiesOfflineMode:1898
    at com__forms_AppointmentForm.lambda$onShowCompleted$14:636
    at com__forms_AppointmentForm__Lambda_9.run:276
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1298
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1242
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1130
    at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
    at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Activity` `internalize` and `externalize` aren't symmetric and you're writing different data than you're reading leading to corruption. You're doing that before the `readUTF` line. By the time you reach the `readUTF` call the data is corrupt hence this error.